# Convolution integral with limits

Tags: python, convolution

I'm trying to implement a convolution integral in Python with limits, but I cannot get it to work.

I have this convolution integral:

[image]

Where t0 is the start year and t is the end year. E is a list of values (one value per year) and G is defined as:

[image]

Where A, alpha and tau are known constants.

Now I need to calculate the result from the convolution integral with the t0 to t limits, but I cannot get it to work. Scipy seems to not have the option to enter the limits. I tried to use the Convolve functions of Scipy and Numpy, but both cannot handle self-chosen limits inside the functions.

Does someone know how to calculate the convolution integral with Python with the limits t0 and t?

Comment: You can use sympy module: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html#concrete-class-reference

Comment: @Goat Solutions Do you have an example of this? I think I should use this one: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/discrete.html#convolution , but then how to provide the limits?

Comment: The integration limits are provided like `sympy.integrate(A, (tau, t0, t))`. It will integrate the function A from t0 to t (for tau)

Comment: But this is not a convolution integral right? I need to know use that with limits.

Comment: It wouldn't work if you replace A (my example) to G*E (your example) ?

Comment: Nope, that's why numpy and scipy both have their own function (convolve) for this type of integral.

Comment: Scipy can evaluated arbitrary definite integrals with quad: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html

Comment: @GaneshGebhard If E is a list of values rather than a function, then it's not clear what you mean by an "integral". In any case, just redefine the function E (or wrap it in another function) so that it is zero outside of the interval from t0 to t. Once you do so, the integral you want is the full convolution integral between G and the modified E.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm sorry for the confusion. What I mean by list is that there is a value for E for every year. So if my t0 is 2023 and my t is 2025, there will be three values for E.

Comment: @Ganesh Ok, but for the purposes of the integral, what is E(t)? For instance, if E(2023) = 1 and E(2024) = 2, then what is E(2023.5)? The integral requires E(t) to be defined for all real valued inputs

Comment: @BenGrossmann E(2023.5) will never occur, only integers.

Comment: @Ganesh Then having E(tau) in the integral formula makes no sense. It sounds like what you actually want is a [discrete convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution), which is a sum rather than an integral.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Okay so what is your suggestion on putting this in Python?

Comment: @GaneshGebhard My suggestion is that before you put anything into Python, you should figure out what you're actually trying to calculate. Another possibility besides the one I suggested is that you *do* want a continuous convolution and that you use E to build a stepwise function so that the integral makes sense. Both this calculation and the previous I suggested are common in the context of signal processing.